# Find the explicit solution of the ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

How to find the explicit solution for this ode.

\begin{equation}
z''-2z^3 + 3z^2 - z = 0
\end{equation}

Suppose $\lim_{s \rightarrow \infty}z = 1$, $\lim_{s \rightarrow -\infty}z = 0$, $\lim_{s \rightarrow \infty}z' = 0$.

This is actually from Evans'PDE Chapter 4.5. I obtain this ode from the given condition. But the question asks to solve this explicitly. The method in the textbook is phase plane analysis which is only helpful for graphing.

Comment: P245, I just solved the ode, your answer is very helpful. I will post a new one later

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Could you consider accepting the answer please, thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Do you mean you post something new? Seems I haven't recieve any notification.

Comment: I meant that you click on the tick sign in the answer

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
& z'' = 2z^3 - 3z^2 + z\\
\cdot z' \implies & z'z'' = 2z^3z' - 3z^2z' + zz' \\
\int dx\implies & \frac{1}{2}z'^2 = 2\frac{1}{4}z^4 -z^3 +\frac{1}{2}z^2 + C_1\\
\cdot2 \implies & z'^2 = z^2(z^2 -2z +1) + C_1\\
\text{reform} \implies & z'^2 = z^2(z-1)^2 + C_1\\
\end{align}
Because of the condition on limit, $C_1$ must be zero
The the equation becomes
\begin{equation}
z' = \pm z(z - 1)
\end{equation}

and we need to solve this ODE. The remaining integral gives the other constant of integration

Comment: Thank you very much! I made a small typo let me edit your answer

Comment: Is it automatic that $z$ doesn't pass through $1$ or $0$ at any point? I am not so sure, unless you can ensure that $C_1$ isn't zero.

Comment: You write $\pm 1$, which implicitly assumes that $z'$ is globally of one sign. But the first order ODE you derived from the conservation law doesn't have enough regularity to prove that. Thus it seems that you could run into the classic $y'=|y|^{1/2},y(0)=0$ scenario. But I guess you don't, somehow or another.

Comment: I think you are probably on the right track: $x^2(x-1)^2 \geq 0$ on $[0,1]$ so you wind up with $\frac{dz}{z(z-1)}$ being equal to...$dt$ I guess, which you can solve. I'm just a bit confused why it cannot stay at $z=0$ or $z=1$ for an arbitrarily long period of time, in the style of $y'=|y|^{1/2}$.

Comment: In fact yeah, once you get to $C_1=0$ you conclude that $z'=|z(z-1)|=z(1-z)$ which is just the logistic equation. So I guess actually $\frac{dz}{z(z-1)}$ was $-dt$ not $+dt$.

Comment: I also see why it cannot stay at $0$ or $1$ for an arbitrarily long period of time now, the reason is that $z'$ actually is Lipschitz after you sort out the square root.